# How open and replace a data from PDF stream in the apache PDFBox lib in java?

Tags: java, pdf, stream, pdfbox

I use **apache pdfbox** **2.0.0** version in my java code (java 1.6).
I'm trying to figure out how I can get, replace and save back to my pdf a data from

```
<stream> data here... <endstream> ?
```

My pdf file looks like:

```
596 0 obj
<<
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 3739
>>
stream
xњ­[ЫnЬF}џoШ8эІАђhЮ/‰`@С%Hvќd-н“іXPJГ ...
endstream
endobj
```

I've found a solution how I can decode this stream. I used a "WriteDecodedDoc" command from the pdfbox-app-1.8.10.jar api.
So now I have two variant of the file but I have NO idea how I can work with this stream.
This stream contains footer and header where were placed images and text.

I checked my file with PDFTextStripper class. It can see necessary data from streams but I can't use this class in case of replacement and saving data back to pdf file.

I tried replace this text just open a file as text, search text, replace it only in stream and save. But I have a problem with "Cannot extract the embedded font...". The main reason is that I loose an encoding. I tried change this encoding but it didn't help me.

BTW I can't use iText. I should use free libs here.

Thanks for any solution.

**Edit:**

after decoding I have the stream like

```
stream
/CS0 CS 0.412 0.416 0.423  SCN
0.25 w 
/GS0 gs
q 1 0 0 1 72 78.425 cm
0 0 m
468 0 l
S
Q
/Span <</Lang (en-US)/MCID 83 >>BDC 
BT
/T1_1 1 Tf
8 0 0 8 237.0609 64.8 Tm
[(www)11(.li)-14.9(nkto)-10(thesi)-8(tesho)-7.9(ouldbehere)15.1(.com)]TJ
/Span<</ActualText<FEFF0009>>> BDC 
( )Tj
endstream
```

I need to replace a link to a different link inside stream. This one:

```
[(www)11(.li)-14.9(nkto)-10(thesi)-8(tesho)-7.9(ouldbehere)15.1(.com)]TJ
```

**EDIT 2**
code

```
public static void replaceLinksInPdf(String filePath) {
        PDDocument document = null;
        try {
            document = PDDocument.load(new File(filePath));
            if (document.isEncrypted()) {
                document.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
                System.out.println(filePath + " Doc was decrypted");
            }

            // COSBase cosb = document.getDocument().getObjects().get(27);
            // e.g. this object contains <stream> bytecode <endstream> in the PDF file.
            // it looks that
            // document -> getDocument() -> objectPool #27 -> baseObject -> randomAccess -> bufferList size 10 has a data that I can't open and work
            // document -> getDocument() -> objectPool #27 -> baseObject -> items -> all PDF's tag but NO a stream section

            int pageNum = 0;
            for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
                PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(page);
                parser.parse();
                List<Object> tokens = parser.getTokens();
                List<Object> newTokens = new ArrayList<Object>();

                for (Object token : tokens) {
                    if (token instanceof Operator) {
                        COSDictionary dictionary = ((Operator) token).getImageParameters();
                        if (dictionary != null) {
                            System.out.println(dictionary.toString());
                        }
                    }
                    if (token instanceof Operator) {
                        Operator op = (Operator) token;
                        if (op.getName().equals("Tj")) {
                            // Tj contains 1 COSString
                            COSString previous = (COSString) newTokens.get(newTokens.size() - 1);
                            String string = previous.getString();
                            // check if string contains a necessary link
                            if (string.equals("www.linkhouldbehere.com")) {
                                COSArray newLink = new COSArray();
                                newLink.add(new COSString("test2.test2.com"));
                                newTokens.set(newTokens.size() - 1, newLink);
                            }
                        } else if (op.getName().equals("TJ")) {
                            // TJ contains a COSArray with COSStrings and COSFloat (padding)
                            COSArray previous = (COSArray) newTokens.get(newTokens.size() - 1);
                            String string = "";
                            for (int k = 0; k < previous.size(); k++) {
                                Object arrElement = previous.getObject(k);
                                if (arrElement instanceof COSString) {
                                    COSString cosString = (COSString) arrElement;
                                    String content = cosString.getString();
                                    string += content;
                                }
                            }
                            // check if string contains a necessary link
                            if (string.equals("www.linkhouldbehere.com")) {
                                COSArray newLink = new COSArray();
                                newLink.add(new COSString("test.test.com"));
                                newTokens.set(newTokens.size() - 1, newLink);
                            } else if (string.startsWith("www.linkhouldbehere.com")) {
                                // some magic here to remove all indents and show new link from beginning.
                                // no rules. Just for test and it works here
                                COSArray newLink = (COSArray) newTokens.get(newTokens.size() - 1);
                                int size = newLink.size();
                                float f = ((COSFloat) newLink.get(size - 4)).floatValue();
                                for (int i = 0; i < size - 4; i++) {
                                    newLink.remove(0);
                                }
                                newLink.set(0, new COSString("test.test.com"));
                                // number for padding of date from right place. Should be checked.
                                newLink.set(1, new COSFloat(f - 8000));
                                newTokens.set(newTokens.size() - 1, newLink);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    newTokens.add(token);
                }

                // save replaced content inside a page
                PDStream newContents = new PDStream(document);
                OutputStream out = newContents.createOutputStream(COSName.FLATE_DECODE);
                ContentStreamWriter writer = new ContentStreamWriter(out);
                writer.writeTokens(newTokens);
                out.close();
                page.setContents(newContents);

                // replace all links that have a pop-up line
                pageNum++;
                List<PDAnnotation> annotations = page.getAnnotations();
                for (PDAnnotation annotation : annotations) {
                    PDAnnotation annot = annotation;
                    if (annot instanceof PDAnnotationLink) {
                        PDAnnotationLink link = (PDAnnotationLink) annot;
                        PDAction action = link.getAction();
                        if (action instanceof PDActionURI) {
                            PDActionURI uri = (PDActionURI) action;
                            String newURI = "www.test1.test1.com";
                            uri.setURI(newURI);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // save file
            document.save(filePath.replace("file", "file_result"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (document != null) {
                try {
                    document.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 3.**

The pdf contains the 660 0 obj that contains a necessary link inside:

```
660 0 obj
<<
/BBox [0.0 792.0 612.0 0.0]
/Length 792
/Matrix [1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0]
/Resources <<
/ColorSpace <<
/CS0 [/ICCBased 21 0 R]
>>
/ExtGState <<
/GS0 22 0 R
>>
/Font <<
/T1_0 834 0 R
/T1_1 835 0 R
/T1_2 836 0 R
>>
/ProcSet [/PDF /Text]
>>
/Subtype /Form
>>
stream
/CS0 CS 0.412 0.416 0.423  SCN
0.25 w 
/GS0 gs
q 1 0 0 1 72 78.425 cm
0 0 m
468 0 l
S
Q
/Artifact <</O /Layout >>BDC 
BT
/CS0 cs 0.412 0.416 0.423  scn
/T1_0 1 Tf
0 Tc 0 Tw 0 Ts 100 Tz 0 Tr 8 0 0 8 72 64.8 Tm
[(Visit )35(O)7(ur site R)23.1(esear)15.1(ch Manager )20.1(on )20(the )12(web at )]TJ
ET
EMC 
/Artifact <</O /Layout >>BDC 
BT
/T1_1 1 Tf
8 0 0 8 237.0609 64.8 Tm
[(www)11(.lin)-14.9(kshou)-10(ldbeh)-8(ere)-7.9(ninechars)15.1(.com)]TJ
/Span<</ActualText<FEFF0009>>> BDC 
( )Tj
EMC 
31.954 0 Td
[(A)15(ugust 7)45.1(,)-5( 2015)]TJ
ET
EMC 
/Artifact <</O /Layout >>BDC 
BT
/T1_0 1 Tf
8 0 0 8 540 64.8 Tm
( )Tj
ET
EMC 
/Artifact <</O /Layout >>BDC 
BT
/T1_2 1 Tf
7 0 0 7 72 55.3 Tm
[(\251 2015 )29(CCH Incorporated and its af\037liates. )38.3(All rights r)12(eserv)8.1(ed.)]TJ
ET
EMC 

endstream
```

and only one place I found where it is called from the pdf file. It is from 45 0 obj

```
/XObject <<
    /Fm0 660 0 R
    /Fm1 661 0 R
>>
```

a full text from obj:

```
45 0 obj
<<
/ArtBox [0.0 0.0 612.0 792.0]
/BleedBox [0.0 0.0 612.0 792.0]
/Contents 658 0 R
/CropBox [0.0 0.0 612.0 792.0]
/Group 659 0 R
/MediaBox [0.0 0.0 612.0 792.0]
/Parent 13 0 R
/Resources <<
/ColorSpace <<
/CS0 [/ICCBased 21 0 R]
>>
/ExtGState <<
/GS0 22 0 R
/GS1 23 0 R
>>
/Font <<
/T1_0 597 0 R
/T1_1 26 0 R
/T1_2 28 0 R
/T1_3 25 0 R
>>
/ProcSet [/PDF /Text]
/XObject <<
/Fm0 660 0 R
/Fm1 661 0 R
>>
>>
/Rotate 0
/StructParents 22
/Tabs /W
/Thumb 662 0 R
/TrimBox [0.0 0.0 612.0 792.0]
/Type /Page
/Annots []
>>
endobj
```

A question is Can I get this 660 0 obj and process it by PDFBox? Because it looks like PDFStreamParser parser doesn't know anythig about this 660 0 object.
Thank you.

Comment: What exactly do you want to replace? A comtent stream, an image, a font?

Comment: a text inside stream. Text and link as a text.

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr, are you a developer from pdfbox? I saw your nickname in pdfbox's examples (tilman)

Comment: Yes that is me. Replacing a content stream is rather easy, however I suspect that there is more to your question: 1) as you see, the link isn't perfect, i.e. it is split, 2) you'll probably have to replace the link annotation as well. Please look at the ReplaceString and ReplaceURLs examples. You can also do the whole thing with NOTEPAD++ (if it is a one time thing), however you must take care that the streams have the same length / same offset as before. (user CTRL-G in NOTEPAD++ to see your positions)

Comment: I already did ReplaceURLs and I didn't found the ReplaceString in examples but I found a working example somewhere from this site. ReplaceURLs works for pop-up links, and ReplaceString works but I had a problem with ligatures. Previously I tried pdfbox 1.8.10. Now I use next code:

Comment: "Next code" you can see in the question. EDIT2. Also as I remember the ReplaceString works for text in the PDFBox 1.8.10. But it doesn't work for stream that appear as bytecode. am I right? I can share my pdf file.

Comment: The problem is not that the content stream is compressed. The problem is that strings are split (as your own example shows: "[(www)11(.li)-14.9(nkto)-10(thesi)-8(tesho)-7.9(ouldbehere)15.1(.com)]TJ"). I had forgotten this was the very reason that it was removed. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1543 So if you want to change many URLs programmatically, you'll have to use heuristics.

Comment: There's also no guarantee that the text is output by one TJ operator. It could also be that the link text is split over several operators. And it could also be that the text isn't readable at all (like in your example) because a font subset is used, so "a" would e.g. be hex 01, "b" be hex 02 or whatever.

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr, I've investigated a content. Please take a look at the EDIT3 from above. I have a question about how can I get and process a obj from XObject <</Fm0 obj>>. Thanks

Comment: Yes, the fun never ends. That is a Form XObject, this has a content stream too. You can get these by going though the XObject resources: do  doc.getPage(page).getResources().getXObjectNames() and resources.getXObject(name) with the names you get, check if the type of the object you get is a PDFormXObject and then go through the content stream from that object. Btw these forms (and pattern objects too!) can have resources, i.e. have Form XObjects or patterns again.

Comment: @Tilman Hausherr, it works!!! Thanks a lot for this!!! I can get a text and parse it by PDFStreamParser par = new PDFStreamParser(xObject.getStream().toByteArray()); ... now I can't find an appropriate way to replace/save this stream back to the pdf. Now I get 2 variants (the old one and the new one are placed together). I should remove the old one

Comment: maybe I don't use a good way to change data from Stream? Do you know  easiest one?

Comment: On a PDStream object, call createOutputStream(). You can write to that.

Comment: If the comments helped you, consider answering the question yourself, maybe it can help others. I didn't write an answer because I felt that this is a bit of a moving target.

Comment: sure. It works for me now. I will add an answer after some tests. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **PDFBox 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT**.
This is my code that works fine for me in case of a links replacement.

Thanks a lot Tilman Hausherr for his help.

```
String filePath = "d:\\pdf\\file1.pdf"
```

...

```
public static void replaceLinksInPdf(String filePath) {
        PDDocument document = null;
        try {
            document = PDDocument.load(new File(filePath));
            // Decrypt a document
            if (document.isEncrypted()) {
                document.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
                System.out.println(filePath + " Doc was decrypted");
            }

            // replace all links in a footer and a header in XObjects with /ProcSet [/PDF /Text]
            // Note: these forms (and pattern objects too!) can have resources,
            // i.e. have Form XObjects or patterns again.
            // If so you need to use a recursion
            for (int pageNum = 0; pageNum < document.getPages().getCount(); pageNum++) {
                List<Object> newPdxTokens = new ArrayList<Object>();
                // Get all XObjects from the page
                Iterable<COSName> xobjs = document.getPage(pageNum).getResources().getXObjectNames();
                for (COSName xobj : xobjs) {
                    boolean isHasTextStream = false;
                    PDXObject pdxObject = document.getPage(pageNum).getResources().getXObject(xobj);
                    // If a stream has not '/ProcSet [/PDF /Text]' line inside it has to be skipped
                    // isXobjectHasTextFieldInPdf has a recursion
                    if (pdxObject.getCOSObject() instanceof COSDictionary) {
                        isHasTextStream = isXobjectHasTextFieldInPdf((COSDictionary) pdxObject.getCOSObject());
                    }

                    if (pdxObject instanceof PDFormXObject && isHasTextStream) {
                        // Set stream from pdxObject
                        PDStream stream = pdxObject.getStream();
                        PDFStreamParser streamParser = new PDFStreamParser(stream.toByteArray());
                        streamParser.parse();
                        for (Object token : streamParser.getTokens()) {
                            if (token instanceof Operator) {
                                Operator op = (Operator) token;
                                if (op.getName().equals("Tj")) {
                                    // Tj contains 1 COSString
                                    COSString previous = (COSString) newPdxTokens.get(newPdxTokens.size() - 1);
                                    String string = previous.getString();
                                    // here can be any filters for checking a necessary string
                                    if (string.equals("www.testlink.com")) {
                                        COSArray newLink = new COSArray();
                                        newLink.add(new COSString("test.test.com"));
                                        newPdxTokens.set(newPdxTokens.size() - 1, newLink);
                                    }
                                } else if (op.getName().equals("TJ")) {
                                    // TJ contains a COSArray with COSStrings and COSFloat (padding)
                                    COSArray previous = (COSArray) newPdxTokens.get(newPdxTokens.size() - 1);
                                    String string = "";
                                    for (int k = 0; k < previous.size(); k++) {
                                        Object arrElement = previous.getObject(k);
                                        if (arrElement instanceof COSString) {
                                            COSString cosString = (COSString) arrElement;
                                            String content = cosString.getString();
                                            string += content;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    // here can be any filters for checking a necessary string
                                    // check if string contains a necessary link
                                    if (string.equals("www.testlink.com")) {
                                        COSArray newLink = new COSArray();
                                        newLink.add(new COSString("test.test.com"));
                                        newPdxTokens.set(newPdxTokens.size() - 1, newLink);
                                    } else if (string.startsWith("www.testlink.com")) {
                                        // this code should be changed. It can have some indenting problems that depend on COSFloat values
                                        COSArray newLink = (COSArray) newPdxTokens.get(newPdxTokens.size() - 1);
                                        int size = newLink.size();
                                        float f = ((COSFloat) newLink.get(size - 4)).floatValue();
                                        for (int i = 0; i < size - 4; i++) {
                                            newLink.remove(0);
                                        }
                                        newLink.set(0, new COSString("test.test.com"));
                                        // number for indenting from right place. Should be checked.
                                        newLink.set(1, new COSFloat(f - 8000));
                                        newPdxTokens.set(newPdxTokens.size() - 1, newLink);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            // save tokens to a temporary List
                            newPdxTokens.add(token);
                        }
                        // save the replaced data back to the srteam
                        OutputStream out = stream.createOutputStream();
                        ContentStreamWriter writer = new ContentStreamWriter(out);
                        writer.writeTokens(newPdxTokens);
                        out.close();
                    }
                }
            }

            // replace data from any text stream from pdf. XObjects not included.
            int pageNum = 0;
            for (PDPage page : document.getPages()) {
                PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(page);
                parser.parse();
                // Get all tokens from the page
                List<Object> tokens = parser.getTokens();
                // Create a temporary List
                List<Object> newTokens = new ArrayList<Object>();

                for (Object token : tokens) {
                    if (token instanceof Operator) {
                        COSDictionary dictionary = ((Operator) token).getImageParameters();
                        if (dictionary != null) {
                            System.out.println(dictionary.toString());
                        }
                    }
                    if (token instanceof Operator) {
                        Operator op = (Operator) token;
                        if (op.getName().equals("Tj")) {
                            // Tj contains 1 COSString
                            COSString previous = (COSString) newTokens.get(newTokens.size() - 1);
                            String string = previous.getString();
                            // here can be any filters for checking a necessary string
                            if (string.equals("www.testlink.com")) {
                                COSArray newLink = new COSArray();
                                newLink.add(new COSString("test2.test2.com"));
                                newTokens.set(newTokens.size() - 1, newLink);
                            }
                        } else if (op.getName().equals("TJ")) {
                            // TJ contains a COSArray with COSStrings and COSFloat (padding)
                            COSArray previous = (COSArray) newTokens.get(newTokens.size() - 1);
                            String string = "";
                            for (int k = 0; k < previous.size(); k++) {
                                Object arrElement = previous.getObject(k);
                                if (arrElement instanceof COSString) {
                                    COSString cosString = (COSString) arrElement;
                                    String content = cosString.getString();
                                    string += content;
                                }
                            }
                            // here can be any filters for checking a necessary string
                            if (string.equals("www.testlink.com")) {
                                COSArray newLink = new COSArray();
                                newLink.add(new COSString("test.test.com"));
                                newTokens.set(newTokens.size() - 1, newLink);
                            } else if (string.startsWith("www.testlink.com")) {
                                // this code should be changed. It can have some indenting problems that depend on COSFloat values
                                COSArray newLink = (COSArray) newTokens.get(newTokens.size() - 1);
                                int size = newLink.size();
                                float f = ((COSFloat) newLink.get(size - 4)).floatValue();
                                for (int i = 0; i < size - 4; i++) {
                                    newLink.remove(0);
                                }
                                newLink.set(0, new COSString("test.test.com"));
                                // number for padding from right place. Should be checked.
                                newLink.set(1, new COSFloat(f - 8000));
                                newTokens.set(newTokens.size() - 1, newLink);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // save tokens to a temporary List
                    newTokens.add(token);
                }
                // save the replaced data back to the document's srteam
                PDStream newContents = new PDStream(document);
                OutputStream out = newContents.createOutputStream(COSName.FLATE_DECODE);
                ContentStreamWriter writer = new ContentStreamWriter(out);
                writer.writeTokens(newTokens);
                out.close();

                // save content
                page.setContents(newContents);

                // replace all links that have a pop-up line (It does not affect the visible text)
                pageNum++;
                List<PDAnnotation> annotations = page.getAnnotations();
                for (PDAnnotation annotation : annotations) {
                    PDAnnotation annot = annotation;
                    if (annot instanceof PDAnnotationLink) {
                        PDAnnotationLink link = (PDAnnotationLink) annot;
                        PDAction action = link.getAction();
                        if (action instanceof PDActionURI) {
                            PDActionURI uri = (PDActionURI) action;
                            String newURI = "www.test1.test1.com";
                            uri.setURI(newURI);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // save document
            document.save(filePath.replace("file", "file_result"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (document != null) {
                try {
                    document.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

an extra method to process only Text stream and skip an image stream. It is called from the main method "replaceLinksInPdf(String filePath)"

```
        // Check if COSDictionary has '/ProcSet [/PDF /Text]' string in the stream
        private static boolean isXobjectHasTextFieldInPdf(COSDictionary dictionary) {
            boolean isHasTextField = false;
            for (COSBase cosBase : dictionary.getValues()) {
                // go to a recursion because COSDictionary can have COSDictionaries inside
                if (cosBase instanceof COSDictionary) {
                    COSDictionary cosDictionaryNew = (COSDictionary) cosBase;
                    // check if '/ProcSet' has '/Text' param
                    if (cosDictionaryNew.containsKey(COSName.PROC_SET)) {
                        COSBase procSet = cosDictionaryNew.getDictionaryObject(COSName.PROC_SET);
                        if (procSet instanceof COSArray) {
                            for (COSBase procSetIterator : ((COSArray) procSet)) {
                                if (procSetIterator instanceof COSName
                                        && ((COSName) procSetIterator).getName().equals("Text")) {
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                        } else if (procSet instanceof COSString && ((COSString) procSet).getString().equals("Text")) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    // go to the COSDictionary children
                    isHasTextField = isXobjectHasTextFieldInPdf(cosDictionaryNew);
                }
            }
            return isHasTextField;
        }
```

It just a testing variant for my project. I will refactor this code with project's rules. You should change replacements as you need. Also I am using this **PDFBox 2.0.0** lib about 1 week and maybe anyone can find more easy way to do some code. Feel free to make a code review and post a more appropriate variant. Thanks.

P.S. I've tested on it 40 PDFs and only 2 of them have to be processed deeply in case of recursion. All 40 files can be open, readable, look as previous version except links